# Sqlalchemy Querying and filtering

Tags: sqlalchemy

So lets say i have some simple classes defined as such

```
class Person
    birthday

class Address
    state
```

and i want the the oldest person from each state, i think i could get it
with something like

```
db.session.query(Address).order_by(Person.birthday.desc()).first()
```

but now i add another class

```
class pet
    species
```

and i want to find the oldest person in each state for each type of species
so from the following...

```
john - MI - dog - 50
alex - MI - dog - 51
joe  - MI - cat - 10
tina - FL - cat - 20
```

I would just want

```
alex, joe, tina
```

but not john, because he wasn't the oldest.

How could i build a query to go about doing that. What topics should i learn 
about?

this is my best attempt so far. This code is specific to my database:

```
def most_recent_completed_uss(user):
    lids = []
    for o in user.organizations:
        for sh in o.survey_headers:
            for ss in sh.survey_sections:
                l = datetime.datetime(1,1,1)
                lid = None
                for uss in ss.user_survey_sections:
                    if o.id == uss.organization.id:
                        if l == datetime.datetime(1,1,1):
                            lid = uss.id
                        if (uss.completed_date and uss.completed_date >= l):
                            l = uss.completed_date
                            lid = uss.id
                lids.append(lid)
    return lids
```

Of course 4 nested for loops and a lack of querying makes me assume this is a less then ideal solution.

Comment: Start here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html

Comment: @TomDignan, care to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PostgreSQL you can use DISTINCT ON (...), which takes the first row in each group. In python:

```py
session.query(Person)
.join(Address, Pet)
.distinct(Address.state, Pet.species)
.order_by(Address.state, Pet.species, Person.birthday)
```

Which will produce something similar to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(address.state, pet.species) person.*
FROM person
JOIN address ON person.address_id = address.id
JOIN pet ON pet.owner_id = person.id
ORDER BY address.state, pet.species, person.birthday
```